# Change style of group title of ObjectList with grouping enabled

Tags: sapui5

When I use grouping in an objectlist the style of the group header is curiously less in stature than seems appropriate for an important piece of information.

How can I re-style the group titles to better reflect their importance in the information hierarchy?

For example, in the snippet below 'Coding 101' and 'Combat 101' are both not as prominent as they might be.

I have been researching online but have not found anything specific on this topic and the panache that the designers of UI5 display in general makes me think that this is catered for without reverting to writing CSS.

```js
// JSON sample data
var data = {
"peeps":  [
    {className: "Coding 101", firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Turing"},
    {className: "Coding 101", firstName: "Ada", lastName: "Lovelace"},
    {className: "Combat 101", firstName: "D", lastName: "Trump"},
    {className: "Combat 101", firstName: "Spartacus", lastName: ""},
    {className: "Combat 101", firstName: "Tasmanian", lastName: "Devil"}

  ]  
};



sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
   "use strict";
   sap.ui.controller("MyController", {
     onInit: function() {

    // create JSON model instance
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

    // set the data for the model
    oModel.setData(data);
       
    var oList = this.getView().byId("SubsList")

    // bind the model to the list
    oList.setModel(oModel);
  
     }
     
   });
   sap.ui.xmlview({
     viewContent: jQuery("#myView").html()
   }).placeAt("content");


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>SAPUI5</title>
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex" data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>

<script id="myView" type="ui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View controllerName="MyController" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:layout="sap.ui.commons.layout" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form">

    <layout:MatrixLayout>
     <layout:rows>
       <layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
         <layout:MatrixLayoutCell backgroundDesign="Fill1" padding="None">

                        <List
                                title="Los Optionales"
                                id="SubsList"
                                width="auto"
                                items="{
                                path: '/peeps',
                                sorter: {
                                    path: 'className',
                                    group: true
                                }}"
                                class="sapUiResponsiveMargin"
                            >
                            <items>
                                <StandardListItem
                                        title="{firstName} {lastName}"
                                        type="Active"
                                />
                            </items>
                            <layoutData>
                                <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
                            </layoutData>
                        </List>


         </layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
        </layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
      </layout:rows>
    </layout:MatrixLayout>
    
                    

  </mvc:View>
</script>

<body class="sapUiBody">
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the factory function for group headers and add a style class shipped with UI5. I must admit that finding a CSS class that fits might be a challenge. Please find an example [here](https://jsbin.com/samodu/edit?html,output).

In your view you just add the `groupHeaderFactory` attribute to the items aggregation settings:

```
<List
    items="{
        path : '/peeps',
        sorter : {
           path: 'className',
           group: true
        },
        groupHeaderFactory : '.createGroupHeader'
    }">
```

In your controller you add the corresponding method:

```
createGroupHeader : function(group) {
    return new GroupHeaderListItem({ 
        "title" : group.key                      
    }).addStyleClass("sapMH1Style");
}
```

[Here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#bindAggregation) you  find all parameters for aggregation binding, including the `groupHeaderFactory`. The usage of factory functions in general is explained [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/335848ac1174435c901baaa55f6d7819.html). The Explored app contains an [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListGrouping/preview) as well.

Comment: Thanks Matbtt - works perfectly. Can I ask - do you know where in the docs this technique is explained?

Comment: Excellent. I was aware of factory functions but had not visited the ManagedObjectModule page in the API viewer so was not aware of the `oBindingInfo.groupHeaderFactory` attribute. I think I shall study this API page.